# how to execute WASM file on emscripten built code on browser

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I want to run wasm on code built with emscripten in a browser.
How can I do this?

example

```cpp
int main(){
  std::ofstream file("user_post_wasm_file");
  auto r = execute_wasm_func(file);  // I want execute_wasm_func
  std::cout<< r + 1 <<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky to do that today because the emscripten-generated JS file is tailored to the particular program being compiled.  i.e. each wasm file gets its own unique JS output that can load that one module.

There has been some discussion of creating a universal JS loader, but its not something you can do today.  If you would like such a feature please open an issue on the emscripten bug tracker (I can't seem to find any existing issue for this, even though I know we have talked about it).